# How to Limit the number of Processes a Program can Generate

Tags: windows-7, memory, crash, process

I'm having an issue where a program called Deadline 7.1 is creating Multiple processes of a Plug-in it uses "MayaBatch" so much to the point it's maxing out the machines memory and causing it to crash.

is there any way to prevent this or limit the number of processes it can create?

System:
Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
80GB Ram
8 Nvidia GTX 980Ti GPUs
Dual Intel Xeon Processors
500gb Samsung SSD

Comment: I’m not aware of Windows offering anything like that. You’d probably need to write a program that scans for processes regularly and kills them as needed. The result would of course always be the same: Whatever you’re doing will likely fail.

Comment: is there anything in Linux that offers it? we're moving to CentOS soon enough, was hoping to get a fix/temp solution on windows for now though

Comment: Ask the dev team to fix it :(